# How to focus on a youtube video player object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, focus, embed

I am making (or trying to make) a chrome plugin that when entering a youtube page, focuses on the video object automatically.

The reasoning for this is that I like to use the space bar to pause the video. However when we enter a youtube video page, it focus on the body. If you press space then, it just scrolls down.

Here is my code.

```
var mp = document.getElementById("movie_player");
setInterval(test,2000);
function test(){
    mp.focus();
    console.log(document.activeElement);
}
onload = mp.focus();
```

I can't seem to focus on the movie_player object. I tried a timer-loop and using the onload. It keeps focusing on the body element.

I know that jQuery can do this no problem. But because the task is so bluntly simple and just needs to work in chrome, I feel jQ is an overkill.

Comment: Did you end up making this? I want it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve the same problem. The solution is to set `tabIndex` first. By default, plugins have an index of -1;

```
function focusMyFlash(name){
    var t=document[name]||window[name];
    if(t){
        t.tabIndex=0;
        t.focus();
    }
}
```

This works in Chrome and FireFox, and I assume it still works in IE (but untested so far).

Comment: Dave, could you please provide an example. I am not able to implement this solution.